# Solr adding document cycle & wait on response issue

Tags: java, solr, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to send http post request to Solr for adding 50000 documents (all individual request one after another in while loop). I am using DefaultHttpClient in java to connect to Solr and when I use execute method on my HttpPost Solr takes 3 to 4 ms to response. I have commit=false, autoCommit=false, autoSoftCommit=false. My question is why it takes that much time to response and why cycle it follows to add new document. 
Basically I want to send add request but do not want to commit to see how many request can Solr handle without doing any kind of commits(without having to do any disk access). My guess is with above parameter tuned off I should be hitting Solr about 10000 times every second, but my result is 300 times a second. I am generating random data to add in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solr can take as many docs, without committing, as you have space in your memory allocated to process (minus regular Solr mem usage).
You might have more when doing this in cloud mode.

If you want to want to push faster, try csv format in batches :)

Comment: I don't want to do batch updates. I want to send update request one at a time and without committing them. My question is why does it take 3 to 4 ms to add one document.

Comment: Is it long in your opinion?

Comment: Yes. Since it does not have to do disk acess